# Running app contained in Docker container in system browser

Tags: docker

I have the following files:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:8

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

`server.js`:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world\n');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "docker_web_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js on Docker",
  "author": "First Last <first.last@example.com>",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.1"
  }
}
```

`.dockerignore`:

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
```

Then I build Docker images:

`docker build -t nodeapp -f ./Dockerfile .`

It works, the image is created. Then I run it:

`docker run -p 49160:8080 -d nodeapp`

And exec following:

`docker exec -it <container id> /bin/bash`

If I type `curl -i localhost:49160`, I get `Failed to connect to localhost port 49160: Connection refused`.

Nonetheless, if I type `curl -i localhost:8080` that's ok:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 12
ETag: W/"c-M6tWOb/Y57lesdjQuHeB1P/qTV0"
Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2019 23:20:41 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Hello world
```

Yet, I can't get `localhost:8080` (neither `localhost:49160`) in the Chrome on my original system, i.e., out of Docker at all.

Is it possible to run dockered apps in browsers? How to fix it to make it work?

---

**EDIT**:

1) I must have checked out an IP address with `docker-machine ip`
2) go to *<docker-machine-ip>:49160*

Comment: From what you describe, accessing the container on port 49160 from the host should be working. You are mapping port 8080 from inside the container, to port 49160 on the host. http://localhost:49160/ should do it. Check the port number in the run command again?

Comment: You are following the guide here: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/ - I just completed it, and I can see the "Hello world" page at http://localhost:49160/ just fine. You need to double check everything I think. I can upload to a repo if you want to compare it?

Comment: I've done things again and still doesn't work. You can upload your one to a repo, it would be more than nice.

Comment: Ok, uploaded here: https://github.com/aplorenzen/nodejs-docker-webapp

Comment: Thanks, yet my files equal yours. Perhaps it has a matter that I'm working on Win10 [?]

Comment: I am on Windows 10 aswell here. Try restarting the docker service? Perhaps something network related is making this difficult. Do you have something that is translating 127.x.x.x addreses somewhere? Or something in your hostfile?

Comment: I've restarted Docker container, before all the process turned off Wamp server... I have no idea what's going on. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: It works when I get IP with `docker-machine ip` command and type it in the browser along with given port.

Comment: Aha, I am not using docker-machine at all. Just [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)

Comment: I meant Docker for Windows requires Win10 Pro or Win10 Student while I have Win10 Home. I'm confused with all the stuff :)